# How to avoid installing files like setup.bash more than once?

Tags: catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I use "catkin build" and "catkin config --install". Then each package will install for example setup.bash. How can I avoid that. I would like to only install these files in one package.

The reason I would like to do that is that I use CPACK to build a debian package for each ros package. And I get duplicate files in the debian packages.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/267427/how-to-avoid-installing-files-like-setup.bash-more-than-once?/) by [tompe17](https://answers.ros.org/users/22519/tompe17/) on ROS Answers with karma: 140 on 2017-07-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can pass the CMake argument `-DCATKIN_BUILD_BINARY_PACKAGE=1` to suppress the generation of setup files. All ROS packages except `catkin` itself use that flag during the release process.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2017-07-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0